# Solving a linear PDE of second order with constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

SOLVE (D^2-DD'-2D'^2)z = (2x^2+xy-2y^2)sin(xy) - cos(xy)
where D & D' are partial derivatives of z w.r.t x & y respectively.

I was able to solve complementary function easily. But I am unable to get particular integral. I used the general method where I divided f(D,D') into factors & substituted y=x+c first. Now this integral has gotten huge & I am unable to solve this. Please suggest me an easy method to find particular integral.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to get result in analytical form? CAS gives particular integral containing Fresnel integrals $C(z)$ and $S(z)$.

Comment: PDE must be (D^2-DD'-2D'^2)z = (2x^2+xy-y^2)sin(xy) - cos(xy). Then particular solution is $z=\sin(xy)$

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas I am unable to solve even that equation. Could you please give a detailed solution for particular integral?

Comment: Particular solution i get with method undetermined coeficients: $z=A\sin xy+B\cos xy$

Comment: Okay, thank you